# Simple menu in console with try and catch

Tags: c#, menu, try-catch

I'm looking all over on how to create a simple menu, that displays the number the user had as an input. Also, I would like to catch any non numeric inputs and write an error message.
Another thing I would like to do is for the console to only exit when the user presses any key, after the output is displayed.

In my scenario, I have no errors, but the console just closes. I tried using `Console.Read();` but it didn't prevent it from exiting.

Here is my code so far:

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace MenuTest2
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Choose an option:");
            Console.WriteLine(" 1. Write Hello");
            Console.WriteLine(" 2. Write jacob");
            int choice = Console.Read();
            try
            {
                switch (choice)
                {
                    case 1:
                        Console.WriteLine("Case 1");
                        Console.ReadLine();
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        Console.WriteLine("Case 2");
                        break;
                    default:
                        Console.WriteLine("Null");
                        break;
                }
            }
            catch (FormatException)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("{0} is not an integer", choice);
            }
            finally
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Press enter to close...");
                Console.ReadLine();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: what error / problem are you facing? You didn't ask any question...

Comment: This try/catch isn't going to do anything. If you want to catch bad input, you need to be looking at the `int choice = Console.Read();` line. Although I'd expect to see `ReadKey` or `ReadLine` instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Console Read gets a single character from your input stream and returns the int32 equivalent. For that reason I wouldn't expect an exception be thrown. As other answers have suggested, make use of the `ReadLine()` function as this will allow for better handling

```
string userInput = Console.ReadLine(); 
if (int.TryParse(userInput, out int choice)) 
{
    switch(choice)
    {
        //etc
    }

}
else 
{
    Console.WriteLine("Invalid - Choice not a numeric response");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you use `ReadLine()` instead of `Read()` when picking the `choice`. Then convert this to an `int` using `Convert.ToInt32(choice)`, and catch that in your try catch.